# Prediction using a model in machine learning python

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

Say I have created a randomforest regression model using test/train data available with me.
This contains feature scaling and categorical data encoding.

Now if I get a new dataset on a new day and I need to use this model to predict the outcome of this new dataset and compare it with the new dataset outcome that I have, do I need to apply feature scaling and categorical data encoding on this dataset as well?

For example .. day 1 I have 10K rows with 6 features and 1 label -- a regression problem
I built a model using this.
On day 2, I get 2K rows with same features and label but of course the data within it would be different.

Now I want to firstly predict using this model and day 2 data, what should be the label as per my model.
Secondly, using this result I want to compare the outcome of the model against the day 2 original label that I have.

So in order to do this, when I pass the day 2 features as the test set to the model, do I need to first do feature scaling and categorical data encoding on them?

This is somewhat to do with making predictions and validating with the received data in order to assess the data quality of the received data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to pass the data to the model in the format it is expecting them. If the model has been trained on scaled, encoded, ... data. You need to do perform all these transformations every time you are pushing new data into the trained model (for whatever reason).

The easiest solution is to use `sklearn`'s `Pipeline` to create a pipeline with all those transformations included and then use it, instead of the model itself to make predictions for new entries so that all those transformations are automatically applied.

example - automatically applying `StandardScaler`'s scaling feature before passing data into the model:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.svm import SVC
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('svc', SVC())])

// then 
pipe.fit...
pipe.score...
pipe.predict...
```

The same holds for dependent variable. If you scaled it before you trained your model, you will need to scale the new ones as well, or you will need to apply inverse operation on the output of the model before you compare it with the original dependent variable values.